# HtmlAgilityPack Asp.Net 1.1 Setup

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack

the htmlagilitypack for asp.net 1.1 (cs files) is different of 2.0+ versions  (dll's) . Anyone remember how to use this in asp.net 1.1?

I tried something like...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" Codebehind="bin/HtmlDocument.cs" src="bin/HtmlDocument.cs"%>
```

But this is using just one of all the cs files, and I get some errors requiring other namespaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the HtmlAgilityPack for Asp.net 1.1 here http://www.codefluent.com/smourier/download/htmlagilitypack.zip in this zip  there are several .cs files. To use this in Asp.net 1.1 just import in the aspx page using the assembly directive

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d864zc1k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Something like this...

```
<%@ Assembly Src="File1.cs" %>
<%@ Assembly Src="File2.cs" %>
```